# How do I dynamically create jQuery ui tabs based on a certain condition?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am dynamically creating tabs with jquery-ui tab component based on a passed in object called children(This functionality if apart of a much larger application).

I'm trying to ensure that the basic functionality/ and or conditions are met with the appropriate `If` statements.

The first condition checks to see if the tab or tabs have been created in the DOM. If it has not then it creates them. The last condition checks to see if the tabs are returned from the object in the appropriate order ie. tab 1, tab2, tab3.

How would I check to see if the return object has the correct order and if not then append the correct order to the DOM?

```
$.each(children, function(i, val) {

            var existingTab = $('#' + val.id, self.container);  
            var existingTabIndex = existingTab.index();



    if(existingTab.length === 0){

            // Add index au
            self.container.tabs('add', '#' + children[i].id, children[i].label,i);



          } else if(existingTabIndex !== val){

                existingTab.index(i);
                this.container.append(val);

          }
        });
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more?

Comment: the Second "Check" or condition i'd like to check to see that the returned order from the children's object is correct. Senario(What if the object is somehow modified and the returned order becomes tab 1, 3, 2. ) That wouldn't be correct so i need to make sure that the returned order of the tabs from the object is always same and if for any reason this changes(ie. In database call or object) that this condition is handled gracefully.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: I'm confused. Do the new tabs need to be correctly ordered just amongst themselves, or amongst the whole collection of existing plus new tabs?

Answer (score 0):

can't you just run a for loop and compare the tabs id to the tab after it and make sure the tab after it is always greater. If even one time the tab after is less(meaning out of order) then change a global variable error to true and now u know theres an error...